# What is the best way to store and return an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I read the docs ([The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0)).

All the videos on Youtube are about `NSUserdefaults` which I think it is the older version of `UserDefaults` right?

Any way to return an array of `Int`, I can do like this:

```
arr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "MyArray") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
```

OR like this:

```
arr = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "MyArray") as? [Int])!
```

Or like this:

```
if let arr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "MyArray") { 

}
```

I am totally confused, I am not sure which way is the best way or what is the difference. Would someone tell me what is the best way to return an array of `Int`, `String`, `Bool`, or an `Any` object `Array`.

Comment: Option 2 is very bad. Options 1 and 3 depend on your needs. Both are valid.

Comment: The "difference" is that they do completely different things. Do the thing that is what you want to do. Or something else. Programming is about putting your desires into computer language. It isn't about picking from a pile of fixed options. Think what you want to do and do it.

Comment: "I think it is the older version of Userdefaults" ... You can think of `UserDefaults` as just the Swift interface for `NSUserDefaults`. Go to the [online documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) and toggle between Swift and Objective-C and it just jumps back and forth between `UserDefaults` and `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: If you were to do `(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "MyArray") as? [Int])!`, you might as well just do `UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "MyArray") as! [Int]`. But both of these will crash if either there is nothing fo the key `MyArray` or if it wasn't an array of `Int`, so you probably would not do that. Only use `!` (in cast or unwrapping) if you know, for a fact, that it can never fail.

Comment: The best option there is your first one which you are using conditional cast combined with the nil coalescing operator to provide a default value in case your defaults haven't being set yet. Note that Swift is a type inferred language so you can just add an empty array after the nil coalescing operator `let arr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "MyArray") as? [Int] ?? []`

Comment: "the best way to return an array of Int" Please note that you cannot return an array of Int unless this is _already_ an array of Int. If that's what you put in, that's what you can get out. If not, not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about `array(forKey:)` is:

- It is an Optional.
- It might be `nil`.
- Even if it is not `nil`, when unwrapped, it will be an untyped array — an `[Any]`.

An Optional must be unwrapped to be useful. An `[Any]` must be cast down to some specific type of array, such as `[Int]`, to be useful. But:

- If you unwrap `nil`, you will crash.
- If you cast something that is not in fact an `[Int]` down to an `[Int]`, you will crash.

Thus, the challenge if you think this might be an `[Int]` is to unwrap the Optional *safely* (without crashing) and cast the resulting array down to an `[Int]` *safely* (without crashing).

That's the goal of your more sensible snippets (the first and third). Bu exactly how you "spell" doing this task makes no difference. It all depends on how you want to proceed if the unwrap or the cast don't work out. Do whatever gives you a coherent result under the circumstances.

Just as a matter of personal style, this is what I would probably say (not one of the options you suggested):

```
if let arr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "MyArray") as? [Int] {
```

The advantage is that it checks that the result is not `nil` and checks that it can be unwrapped and cast down to `[Int]`, and does so, safely, if the answer is yes, all in one move.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is highly appreciated. But just to make sure I can differentiate between unwrapping and nil, do you think this is right?
`if let myObj = UserDefaults.... {}` This is unwrapping
`if myObj != nil {}` This check for nil.
correct ?

Comment: Yes, although you can do more than that. `if let myObj = UserDefaults.... as? [Int]` will do it all in one move: it checks that the result is `nil` and it checks that it can be cast down to `[Int]` and proceeds only if the answer to both is yes. That wasn't one of your options, but it is what I personally would do. I'll add that to my answer.